# Clean pipeline of operations in python

Tags: python, functional-programming, pipeline

I have a long pipeline which does various operations to a list of strings `input_list`. The pipeline maps each word to lowercase, replaces underscores, filters out a specific word, remove duplicates, and clips to a certain length.

```
result = list(set(filter(lambda x : x != word, map(lambda x : x.lower().replace('_',' '), input_list))))[:clip_length]
```

My problem with this is its not very readable: its not very clear what the input to this pipeline is and in what order operations are applied. It hurts to look at a bit, and I probably won't know what it does later on unless its been nicely commented.

Is there any way to write a pipeline in python where I can clearly see which operations happen in what order, what goes in and what goes out? To be more specific, I'd like to be able to write it so that operations go either right-to-left or left-to-right, not inner-to-outer.

Comment: Is this off topic? Might just have to accept this as the nature of python, but surely there's a nicer way...?

Comment: Python is not a functional programming language, although it provides several functional programming constructs. To maintain readability, consider using a comprehesion construct (e.g. a list comprehension) instead of `filter(..., map(..., map(...)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it's functional, but it has no (consistent) style. The "problem" is the wide variety of syntaxes used for these expressions.

- calling a func is done with normal prefix notation `f(arg)`
- getting a sub array uses a special syntax `arr[n?:m?]`, instead of a function `slice(n,m)`
- `set` is a completely different type, but it is used intermediately to because sets happen to have *some* of the behavior we want - what we want is "unique" elements in an iterable, and so our function should be called `unique`. If we happen to implement `unique` using a `set`, that's fine, but that is not the concern of the reader, whose mind is free from such distractions
- `x.lower()` is a dynamic call with `lower` in infix position. Compare to prefix position `lower(x)`. The same applies for `s.replace(pat,rep)` vs `replace(s, pat, rep)`
- `map` and `filter` however do have a functional interface `map(f,iter)` and `filter(f,iter)`

But to write a program like the one you've shared, sort of misses out on functional style's strongest and most versatile trait: the function. Yes, functional programming is also about composing beautiful chains of expressions, but not at the cost of readability! If readability starts to hurt, make it better with... a function :D

Consider this program that uses a *uniform* functional style. It's still a regular python program.

```
def program (word = '', clip_length = 5, input = ''):
  make_words = \
    compose ( lower
            , partial (replace, '_', ' ')
            )

  process = \
    compose ( partial (map, make_words)
            , partial (filter, lambda x: x != word)
            , unique
            , partial (take, clip_length)
            )

  return process (input)

print (program ('b', 4, 'A_a_a_B_b_b_c_c_c_d_e'))
# ['d', ' ', 'e', 'a']
# Note, your output may vary. More on this later.
```

And now the dependencies. Each function operates solely on its arguments and returns an output.

```
def partial (f, *xs):
  return lambda *ys: f (*xs, *ys)

def compose (f = None, *fs):
  def comp (x):
    if f is None:
      return x
    else:
      return compose (*fs) (f (x))
  return comp

def take (n = 0, xs = []):
  return xs [:n]

def lower (s = ''):
  return s .lower ()

def replace (pat = '', rep = '', s = ''):
  return s .replace (pat, rep)

def unique (iter):
  return list (set (iter))
```

Really, this question couldn't have setup a better stage for some of these bullet points. I'm going to revisit the choice of `set` as used in the original question (and in the program above) because there's a huge problem: if you re-run our program several times, we will get a *different* output. In fancier words, we have no [referential transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency). That's because Python's sets are unordered, and when we convert from an ordered list, to a set, then back to a list, it's not guaranteed that we'll always get the same elements.

Using `set` this way shows good intuition on how to solve the uniques problem using existing language features, but we want to restore referential transparency. In our program above, we clearly encoded our intention of getting an inputs unique elements by calling the `unique` function on it.

```
# deterministic implementation of unique
def unique (iter):
  result = list ()
  seen = set ()
  for x in iter:
    if x not in seen:
      seen .add (x)
      result .append (x)
  return result
```

Now when we run our program, we *always* get the same result

```
print (program ('b', 4, 'A_a_a_B_b_b_c_c_c_d_e'))
# ['a', ' ', 'c', 'd']
# always the same output now
```

This brings me to another point. Because we abstracted `unique` into its own function, we're automatically given a scope to define its behavior in. I chose to use imperative style in `unique`'s implementation, but that's fine as it is still a pure function and the consumer of the function cannot tell the difference. You can come up with 100 other implementations of `unique` so long as `program` works, it doesn't matter.

Functional programming is about *functions*. The language is yours to tame. It's still a regular python program.

```
def fwd (x):
  return lambda k: fwd (k (x))

def program (word = '', clip_length = 5, input = ''):
  make_words = \
    compose ( lower
            , partial (replace, '_', ' ')
            )

  fwd (input)                               \
    (partial (map, make_words))             \
    (partial (filter, lambda x: x != word)) \
    (unique)                                \
    (partial (take, clip_length))           \
    (print)

program ('b', 4, 'A_a_a_B_b_b_c_c_c_d_e')
# ['a', ' ', 'c', 'd']
```

Touch and experiment with this program on [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/PreviousJudiciousFlash)

Comment: Nice, but just a style tip: consider using parentheses instead of back-slash line-continuation. Then it's almost as if you were writing lisp... :)

Comment: The advantage `fwd` provides is sequencing calls using ` \ (...) \ (...) ...` or arbitrary limit without having to nest parentheses `(...(...(...)))`. It's just an example to demonstrate you can invent your own convenience, of course within the boundaries set by python's parser :D

Comment: Oh man, what a fantastic answer. Really appreciate this, it really gets right to the bottom of my concern. Clearly I have much to learn...

Answer (score 2):

That's functional-style, which you can read from innermost expression towards outermost.

Putting it on multiple lines with some comments can help readability:

```
result = list(                                # (5) convert to list
  set(                                        # (4) convert to set (remove dupes)
    filter(
      lambda x: x != word,                    # (3) filter items != to word
      map(
        lambda x: x.lower().replace('_',' '), # (2) apply transformation
        input_list                            # (1) take input_list
      )
    )
  )
)[:clip_length]                               # (6) limit number of results
```

It's a matter of taste. I tend to prefer single expressions like this, with a minimal formatting that would allow it to fit nicely:

```
result = list(set(filter(lambda x : x != word,
    map(lambda x : x.lower().replace('_',' '), input_list))))[:clip_length]
```

An equivalent imperative-style processing is:

```
result = set()
for x in input_list:
    x = x.lower().replace('_', ' ')
    if x != word:
        result.add(x)
result = list(result)[:clip_length]
```

Comment: I guess it's a matter of style so off topic. I just really don't like how it reads. I'd like to be able to write it so that operations go right to left or left to right. I suppose multiple lines makes it a bit nicer but prefer a one-liner. I guess I'll just have to accept this